# Заменить URL веб сайта

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть, допустим, `мойсайт.ru`. На нем стоит скрипт для ранжирования галереи.
Как мне поменять URL на `мойсайт.top`?

Answer (score 3):

> как мне поменять урл на мойсайт.top

Купить домен `мойсайт.top`, сделать алиасом к `мойсайт.ru`.

В php-скриптах прописать:

```
<?php
header(“HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently”);
header(“Location: http://мойсайт.top/”);
exit();
?>
```

Не забывая прописывать адреса страниц.

Но лучше в `.htaccess`:

```
Redirect 301 / http://мойсайт.top/
```

[см подробней и др варианты](http://htaccess.net.ru/doc/Redirect/index.php)

Кириллические домены нужно преобразовывать в [Punycode](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)

Comment: @Crantisz, а в чём правка состояла? Что я не так сделал? Что-то не вижу разницы.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/617888/revisions

Comment: Не вижу разницы, я ж говорил. какой "убрал сниппет"?. Код удалён и тот код же вставлен.

Comment: Вы используете сниппет там где это не нужно. Он предназначен для запуска js/css/html кода, а не php, который, естественно, не работает.

Comment: плюсующие и отвечающие, кто нибудь понял суть вопроса, автор хочет сменить на сервере в скрипте что он пробывал сделать и т.д.?

Comment: Хочет сменить домен, не потеряв трафик на старый (второе опционально)

Comment: да именно не потеряв трафик .index.php на нем галлерея инклюдиться.чтоб на втором выводилась таже галлерея